# Is there a way to auto create a databse in typeORM?

Tags: node.js, nestjs, typeorm

I am migrating from sequelizeORM to typeORM. In sequelize-cli there are nice commands to drop database and create a new one for example:

```
node_modules/.bin/sequelize db:drop
node_modules/.bin/sequelize db:create
node_modules/.bin/sequelize db:migrate
```

Ok, for typeORM I know how to run migration but I can't find anywhere how to automatically create or drop a database. Tnx in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can also use [typeorm-extension](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typeorm-extension) package, to `create` or `drop` the database specified for the connection, for nearly all database driver.
The package also parses the extra parameter `charset` and `characterSet` of the extra parameter (ENV: TYPEORM_DRIVER_EXTRA)

```js
import {createDatabase} from "typeorm-extension";

(async () => {
    await createDatabase({ifNotExist: true});
   
    await dropDatabase({ifExist: true});

    process.exit(0);
})();
```

You can also provide the `charset` and `characterSet` as properties for the first parameter to the `createDatabase()` function.
F.e

- postgres

```js
createDatabase({ifNotExist: true, characterSet: "UTF8"});
```

- mysql

```js
createDatabase({ifNotExist: true, charset: "utf8mb4_general_ci", characterSet: "utf8mb4"});
```

If you have any questions or concerns feel free to contact me or contribute to the codebase on [Github](https://github.com/Tada5hi/typeorm-extension/issues)

Comment: Be careful about using this library on production, any unwanted changes in the library can wipe out your database!

Answer (score 6):

you can use the CLI tool `typeorm schema:drop` or if you want to drop and recreate the database on each startup, you can use

```
{
...
  dropSchema: true,
...  
  "migrations": [
    "dist/migrations/**/*.js"
  ]
}
```

where you do your connection options and set migrations path, and so forth.

Comment: Be careful not to use it on the production environment!!!

Comment: Production environments should always be handled with care ‍♂️ Although if you have seeds and “runMigrations: true” you might be able to get away with it, depending on circumstances

Comment: does it really answer the question? What is the way to create database?

Comment: @РоманСоляник Setting 'dropSchema: true' drops the database when the application is started, after which the database specified with entities and migrations (given that runMigrations is set to true) is created. So in effect it's a sort of "drop and recreate".